# How to change the title of chapter style

Tags: chapters, titles, section-titles, displaystyle

It's the first time that I am using LaTeX and I am struggling to change the style format of the title chapter. In particular, I am running this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tocloft} %To personalize table of contents

%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} To add sections in the table of contents 
\textwidth=450pt\oddsidemargin=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
 
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter[First chapter]{Introduction}
\section{First section}
\end{document}
```

and I obtain this style:

[image]

But I would like to obtain this:

[image]

How can I obtain it ?

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{quotchap}`. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/quotchap/quotchap.pdf): "This package redefines
the \chapter and \chapter* commands to create fancy chapter head pages
with huge chapter numbers (possibly greyed)".

Comment: Thank you very much. @Marijn .